# csrf fail on restAuth with TokenAuthentication and corsheaders

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman, django-rest-auth, django-cors-headers

I am trying to make auth apis for my django+react project. I have used restauth package. When I hit the api with postman, it is successful (200) on get request but fails on post request due to csrf, I looked on internet and disabled sessionauthentication but still in vain .Here is my settings.py minimal settings for restauth

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic"
]
LOCAL_APPS = [
    "users.apps.UsersConfig",
    "corsheaders",
]
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "rest_auth_custom",
    "rest_auth_custom.registration",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.google",
]
INSTALLED_APPS += LOCAL_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    )
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
```

here is the postman view. let me know if you need anything additional

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a header X-CSRFToken while requesting a method that can potentially change a state on the server-side. For example, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE etc.

"headers" : { "X-CSRFToken":"token" }

The value of X-CSRFToken is set by the server when the user is authenticated. The server uses a header named **set-cookie** having a name **csrf** and value **somevalue** that can be used later in **X-CSRF-Token** header. Here is a link to complete documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-and-csrf-cookie-httponly-are-false